# Customizing schema fields in sanity.io

Tags: javascript, json, sanity

In sanity studio schema I made some object type with one field, dependent of other. If "all" field check to true, then "date" field should be hidden or disabled.

But I don't know how to realize it. I tried to find examples, or guides in docs, but found nothing.

```js
const dateTime = {
  name: 'dateTime',
  type: 'object',
  fields: [
    {
      name: 'all',
      type: 'boolean',
    },
    {
      name: 'date',
      type: 'date',
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: #### Conditional fields have come to Sanity.io! https://www.sanity.io/docs/conditional-fields Apparently there was a custom component in the "exchange"... https://www.sanity.io/schemas/conditional-fields-106f447e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Sanity Studio doesn't currently have an out-of-the-box way of doing this. But, it could certainly be solved by creating a [custom input component](https://www.sanity.io/docs/custom-input-widgets) for that boolean field. The custom input would then typically set the fields value depending on the state of any other fields you choose to inspect.

Someone else has [also requested this feature](https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity/issues/677). If you want to jump in there and voice your opinion and state what you need if for, that would be very useful!

Comment: Happy to help @DaryaMoreno-Gogoleva! Remember do set my response as "answered". That helps other people find what they're looking for.

Comment: In a custom input component, how do you get the context of the form or other fields in the form though? I want to do something a long the lines of this in the `onChange` for the all boolean's custom input component: `form.setValue(['date', 'hidden'], !!state.checked)`

Maybe I'm missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: Adam, you can acess the form context in the "document" props, passed by sanity to the custom input component.